# PGSimpleDataSource + HikariCP long connection acquisition time

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-9.1, hikaricp

Have a Spring boot app `1.4.1.RELEASE`. During service boot, I can see Hikari connection pool is created with below configurations however it takes very long to acquire JDBC connection. Here is from the logs:

```
**34880058484** nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
8074041 nanoseconds spent preparing 6 JDBC statements;
58549577 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC statements;
350394122 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
394751462 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 4 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

build.gradle relevant configurations:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
}
// HikariCP
compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
}

// Need this in order to get the HikariCPConnectionProvider
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.2.11.Final') {
    exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core'
}
```

spring.datasource configuration:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

HikariCP configurations:

```
# Hikari will use the above plus the following to setup connection pooling
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-class-name=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.user=${spring.datasource.username}
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.password=${spring.datasource.password}
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.reWriteBatchedInserts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=SessionServiceHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 from session
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
```

Application.java

```
@Bean
public HikariDataSource hikariDataSource() throws Exception{
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
}
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
public HikariConfig hikariConfig() throws Exception{
    return new HikariConfig();
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new JdbcTemplate(hikariDataSource());
}
```

It seems the connection is not being used from the pool but JDBC creates a new connection everytime. What could be the reason?

Comment: Why are you manually configuring the datasource? Also the dependency on `org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.2.11.Final` shouldn't be there and you should be messing around with `spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class` (although that doesn't do anything as the property is wrong). You are using an externally managed connection pool. You shouldn't be using `connection-test-query` that is only for non JDBC 4 drivers (so remove it). Also remove the `getJdbcTemplate` method as Spring Boot will configure that as well.

Comment: removing getJDBCTemplate solved the problem.I was in impression that we need to explicitly tell boot to use Hikari DS for JDBC template but that isnt the case. thanks for the comment. if you can put it as answer, I can accept it.